# Telerik Kendo UI MVC Schedular not able to add a textbox resource

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, telerik-scheduler

I am developing a Schedular using telerik Kendo UI MVC Schedular with Razor engine. I have added some of dropdown resources. All works fine.

But I tried to add one textbox resource , I googled but found nothing.

My Stuffs:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<KendoUITEST.Models.TaskViewModel>()
    .Name("scheduler")

    .Date(new DateTime(2013, 6, 13))
    .StartTime(new DateTime(2013, 6, 13, 7, 00, 00))
    .Height(600)
    .Views(views =>
    {
        views.DayView();
        views.WeekView(weekView => weekView.Selected(true));
        views.MonthView();

    })
    .Timezone("Etc/UTC")
    .DataSource(d => d
        .Model(m =>
        {
            m.Id(f => f.TaskID);
            m.Field(f => f.OwnerID).DefaultValue(1);
            //Set the recurrence ID field from the model:
            m.RecurrenceId(f => f.RecurrenceID);
        })
        .Read("Tasks_Read", "Schedular")
        .Create("Tasks_Create", "Schedular")
        .Destroy("Tasks_Destroy", "Schedular")
        .Update("Tasks_Update", "Schedular")
    )
    .Resources(resource =>
         {
             resource.Add(m => m.AgencyId)
                 .Title("Agency")
                 .DataTextField("Text")
                 .DataValueField("Value")
                 .DataColorField("Color")
                 .BindTo(new[] { 
                    new { Text = "Meeting Room 101", Value = 1, Color = "#6eb3fa" },
                    new { Text = "Meeting Room 201", Value = 2, Color = "#f58a8a" } 
                });
             resource.Add(m => m.CityStateZip)
             .Title("City State Zip")
             .DataTextField("Text")
             .DataValueField("Value")
             .DataColorField("Color")
             .BindTo(new[] { 
                    new { Text = "Meeting Room 101", Value = 1, Color = "#6eb3fa" },
                    new { Text = "Meeting Room 201", Value = 2, Color = "#f58a8a" } 
                });
             resource.Add(m => m.POC)
         .Title("POC")
         .DataTextField("Text")
         .DataValueField("Value")
         .DataColorField("Color")
         .BindTo(new[] { 
                    new { Text = "Meeting Room 101", Value = 1, Color = "#6eb3fa" },
                    new { Text = "Meeting Room 201", Value = 2, Color = "#f58a8a" } 
                });
             resource.Add(m => m.EventType)

    .Title("Event Type")
    .DataTextField("Text")
    .DataValueField("Value")
    .DataColorField("Color")
    .BindTo(new[] { 
                     new { Text = "Agency Visit", Value = 1, Color = "#6eb3fa" },
                    new { Text = "Phone Call", Value = 2, Color = "#f58a8a" } ,
                     new { Text = "Trade Show", Value = 1, Color = "#6eb3fa" },
             new { Text = "SIU Event", Value = 1, Color = "#6eb3fa" }

                });

         })
 //Need to add a textbox resource

)
```

Output:

[image]

Question:
How to add radiobutton, textbox and other controls to Kendo MVC Schedular?

Little help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: I am having the same problem, still no solution. Please let me know if you found any solution.